# 2 separate $_POST sent to the same file

Tags: javascript, php, json, post

I'm making a form, and when filled out, it sends all of its items to post. Json encoded it looks like this.

```
{
    "encounterName":"Violence",
    "encounterHint":"",
    "basicTrainingSectionSlide":["1","6"],
    "basicTrainingContentHeader":["2","4"],
    "basicTrainingContentText":["3","5"],
    "contextText_1":"",
    "contextText_2":"",
    "contextText_3":"",
    "contextText_4":"",
    "contextText_5":"",
    "submit_form":"Submit"
}
```

However, there's a specific array in a .js file that is finalized when the form submits. It basically keeps track of which buttons are pressed in which order, so I can spit out information in that order. The function looks like this.

```
function returnValues() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "final.php",
        data:{ Sections: $sectionOrder }, 
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); 
        }
    })
}
```

Yet now, when I json encode the post, I get this:

```
{
    "encounterName":"Violence",
    "encounterHint":"",
    "basicTrainingSectionSlide":["1","6"],
    "basicTrainingContentHeader":["2","4"],
    "basicTrainingContentText":["3","5"],
    "contextText_1":"",
    "contextText_2":"",
    "contextText_3":"",
    "contextText_4":"",
    "contextText_5":"",
    "submit_form":"Submit"
}

{
    "Sections":["","Section","Text","Text","Section"]
}

{
    "Sections":["","Section","Text","Text","Section"]
}
```

Furthermore, once the sections part of post gets called into a foreach loop as such:

```
foreach($_POST['Sections'] as $order){
        file_put_contents($_POST['encounterName'].".json", "\t\t\t\"".$_POST['basicTrainingSectionSlide'][0]."\"\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

`$_POST['encounterName']` ends up equaling ".json" and `$_POST['basicTrainingSectionSlide'][0]` becomes and empty string until the loop is done.

This is what var_dump returns:

```
array(11) { ["encounterName"]=> string(8) "Violence" ["encounterHint"]=> string(0) "" ["basicTrainingSectionSlide"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "6" } ["basicTrainingContentHeader"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "4" } ["basicTrainingContentText"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "5" } ["contextText_1"]=> string(0) "" ["contextText_2"]=> string(0) "" ["contextText_3"]=> string(0) "" ["contextText_4"]=> string(0) "" ["contextText_5"]=> string(0) "" ["submit_form"]=> string(6) "Submit" } array(11) { ["encounterName"]=> string(8) "Violence" ["encounterHint"]=> string(0) "" ["basicTrainingSectionSlide"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "6" } ["basicTrainingContentHeader"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "4" } ["basicTrainingContentText"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "5" } ["contextText_1"]=> string(0) "" ["contextText_2"]=> string(0) "" ["contextText_3"]=> string(0) "" ["contextText_4"]=> string(0) "" ["contextText_5"]=> string(0) "" ["submit_form"]=> string(6) "Submit" }
```

I need that information in that loop.

Comment: Can you please post what var_dump($_POST) returns?

Comment: From the included vardump, it looks like "Sections" are not part of the _POST at all.

Comment: Yes, the whole thing's confusing. I can call it from my php file, but it comes in separately.

Comment: You would need to include more of JS code. Sounds like you have some mistake in your logic.

Comment: That's all the logic right there.

Comment: This code in JS:

`function returnValues() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "final.php",
        data:{ Sections: $sectionOrder }, 
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); 
        }
    })
}`

does not explain the current structure of your _POST in PHP.

It is rather a problem with when/what you submit in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, so, to boil it down, there are buttons in my form that open up new form fields, one for a 'Section' and one for 'Text'. You can open them up in any order and they have to be printed to a file in the order opened. In my javascript code, I keep track of what's been opened via an array. But when the form is uploaded, I have to send that array to a validation form, where it and the data entered can work together to properly order. That function is called onsubmit in the form tag.

Comment: It won't work this way then. Each time you are posting the data, you are calling the PHP script separately by making a separate HTTP request, therefore you are not passing "encounterName" at all. This is why the filename is getting lost.

Comment: It took a while, but yeah, you're right. For some reason their was residual $_POST from both sections, but they couldn't be called simultaneously in the form. I ended up being able to append hidden input tags with the values I needed. Thanks though.